# Material clipping GLB Export

Tags: mesh, rigging, export, gltf

Upon using auto-rig pro to rig a character, I posed and exported in glb/gltf format.  When I look at it in a glb/gltf viewer, the closer I get, portions of the rigged object abruptly disappear, seemingly by object/material.  I don't believe this is the clipping plane, because there is no transition, its just there, and then one wheel roll (click) forward, and it disappears.  This also does not happen to other non-rigged objects in the scene.  Has anyone else had this issue, or suggestions on what to check?

Thank you in advance.

[image: AS soon as I scroll to zoom in , parts of the rigged character abruptly disappear]

Answer (score 1):

A solution has been found...Applying the rig (modifier) to the character after the pose seemed to resolve the issue.